# Devices supporting allshare framework

Tags: android, sdk, samsung-smart-tv, samsung-mobile-sdk

Does anyone who has used Samsung's allshare sdk tell me what mobile devices support allshare framework? As I am not able to run any custom allshare apps developed using the allshare sdk.

I keep getting run time errors - "All share Service is not installed on this device"

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From Samsung's site:

> The AllShare Framework is pre-installed on the Samsung Galaxy S4, Samsung HomeSync, Samsung Galaxy S3, Samsung Note 10.1, Samsung Note 2 and Samsung Galaxy Camera series. It will be installed by default on further Samsung Smart Phones and Smart Camera production models.

http://developer.samsung.com/allshare-framework/technical-docs/FAQ

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have read this before and I tried running my app on S4, Note 5, S6 and S6 edge plus. But, I was getting the same runtime exception on all of them.

I have attached the screenshot with this.